# Read nested json objects that have been serialized via gson library

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

I am storing an object in shared preferences. To do this I am serializing the object using the gson library and a typeadapter before storing them.

Here's what my object looks like in json:

```
    {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Sensor 2D:D3:5C",
    "address": "00:07:80:2D:D3:5C",
    "device": {
    "mAddress": "00:07:80:2D:D3:5C"
    },
    "temp": "31342e37"
    }
```

This all works, but not when deserializing the "device" because it is a BluetoothDevice object instead of a simple string or int value. How can I tell my TypeAdapter to properly deserialize this?

Here's a look at the read method of my typeadapter:

```
    @Override
    public myDevice read(final JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        final myDevice dv= new myDevice();
        in.beginObject();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            switch (in.nextName()) {
                case "id":
                    dv.setId(in.nextInt());
                    break;
                case "name":
                    dv.setName(in.nextString());
                    break;
                case "address":
                    dv.setAddress(in.nextString());
                    break;
                case "temp":
                    dv.setTemp(in.nextString());
                    break;
                case "device":
                    //What do I do here??
                    //dv.setDevice(in.????);
                    break;
            }
        }
        in.endObject();
        return vd;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason to use a `TypeAdapter` instead of mapping directly the JSON into an object? For instance with:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Info info = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Info.class)
```

If you need to use the `JsonReader`, then you could consider using `JsonToken` by calling `reader.peek()`. You will then be able to `switch` over token types (`BEGIN_OBJECT`, `END_OBJECT`, `BEGIN_ARRAY`, `STRING`...).

Comment: this is what I was originally using, and it works for deserialization of this without a problem, but upon serializing I would get a stackoverflow error. I think this was because I was hitting a recursion limit, so specifying exactly what I wanted serialized via typeadapter seems to have resolved that issue. I can see the type for device is BEGIN_OBJECT using peek(), but how do I get that object and turn it back into a BluetoothDevice object from within this read method?

Comment: I accepted your answer because I was able to use the typeadapter to serialize the data, while mapping directly into an object when the object was read back in. Body of read method becomes only 3 lines of code:         
        myDevice dv;
        dv= gson.fromJson(in, myDevice.class);
        return dv;